# Cucumber Gherkin Code generation automation

Tags: java, jenkins, cucumber-jvm, gherkin, cucumber-java

The initial step definition file(skeleton) is being generated by Cucumber Plugin in Eclipse. (i.e Right Click-> Run as -> Cucumber Feature)

I want to automate this whole step either using Java Code or Jenkins Scripting.

My question is :

Is cucumber-java plugin helping to achieve this ? (Some code triggers this automation) Or Do I need to write my own logic for generating this Gherkin ?

Comment: You don't want to generate these skeletons using an automated tool. They are meant as a starting point for the automation and as such, anyone who implements the step should use them. This is a person. The snippets may be created using Eclipse or you may use the suggestions generated from Cucumber when it can't find a corresponding step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669406/how-to-implement-step-definitios-from-gherkin-feature-files?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138833/is-there-a-way-to-directly-generate-step-definitions-in-eclipse-without-running?rq=1